# How to make the SSIS package status to failure when propagate was set to false for a Sequence container

Tags: error-handling, ssis, foreach-loop-container

I have an SSIS package with for each loop > sequence container. The sequence container is trying to read file from For each loop and process its data. The requirement was to not fail the entire package when any exception happened in processing a file but to continue processing the next file until all the files were processed from the for each loop. For this, I have set the Propagate variable for the sequence container to False. I have also added email step on On Error event of Sequence container. The package is running as expected and able to process all files even when any exception happened with any file. But I would like the status of my SSIS package to be failed finally since one of the files got failed. How can I achieve that ?

Comment: Please, show your solution and shortly repeat what do you want to change. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I cannot share the solution. I have set the sequence container propagate variable to false to allow processing of all files in a for each loop container. but I want to set the package status to fail finally if any of the file processing was failed inside the sequence container.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this options?
(SSIS version in russian on the left side but it's sequence container)
[image]

View -> Properties window -> Then click on your sequence container and it will show you ther properties of sequence container.

If i were you first of all i would try property "FailPackageOnFailture" - it should cover your question if i get it right.

P.S. Also you can see the whole properties of your project when you click on a free place in your project

UPDATED (after comments and more clear understanding task):
The idea is - set this param Maximum ErrorCount for SQ as max as you want - in this case it wont stop the package because 1 of the files was failed in SQ and next file will process, but it should stop package after SQ will finish his work because you don't change MaximumErrorCount for package.
Important - a value of zero sets the error count threshold to infinity and package or task never get's Failure

Comment: @user3044602 pls tell me if it helps you

Comment: I have tried that option. That will stop the execution of the package and cannot process the next file in the for each loop, which will defeat my purpose.

Comment: @user3044602 then try to play with Maximum ErrorCount (just for SQ) - set 99, save project and run it

Comment: The idea is - set this param as max as  you want - in this case it wont stop the package and next file will process, but it should stop package afte SQ will finish his work because you don't change MaximumErrorCount for package

Comment: if i'm not mistaken about the last one

Comment: A value of zero sets the error count threshold to infinity and package or task never get's Failure